# MainApplication.java:9: Error: Packagecom.reactnativecommunity.webview does not exist

Tags: react-native

> % npx react-native run-android Starting JS server... Building and
> installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew
> installDebug)...
>
> > Configure project :react-native-reanimated WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored, as it is below
> > the minimum supported version (29.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin
> > 4.1.0. Android SDK Build Tools 29.0.2 will be used. To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" from your build.gradle
> > file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default
> > version of the build tools. Warning: Mapping new ns
> > http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns
> > http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01 Warning:
> > Mapping new ns
> > http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns
> > http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01 Warning:
> > Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02
> > to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
> > Warning: Mapping new ns
> > http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns
> > http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01 Warning:
> > Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02
> > to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
>
> > Configure project :react-native-linear-gradient WARNING: Configuration 'provided' is obsolete and has been replaced with
> > 'compileOnly'. It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle
> > plugin. For more information, see
> > http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
>
> > Configure project :react-native-orientation WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and
> > 'api'. It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> > For more information, see
> > http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
>
> > Configure project :app WARNING: The option 'android.useDeprecatedNdk' is deprecated. The current default is
> > 'false'. It has been removed from the current version of the Android
> > Gradle plugin. NdkCompile is no longer supported WARNING:
> > Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
> > 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed in version 5.0 of the
> > Android Gradle plugin. For more information, see
> > http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
> > WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been
> > replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'. It will be
> > removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin. For more
> > information, see
> > https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance. To
> > determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use
> > -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information. WARNING: API 'variant.getPackageApplication()' is
> > obsolete and has been replaced with
> > 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'. It will be removed in
> > version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin. For more information, see
> > https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance. To
> > determine what is calling variant.getPackageApplication(), use
> > -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information. WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and
> > has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'. It will be
> > removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin. For more
> > information, see
> > https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance. To
> > determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use
> > -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>
> > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:9:
> > Error: Packagecom.reactnativecommunity.webview does not exist import
> > com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewPackage;
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:18:
> > Error: Packagecom.beefe.picker does not exist import
> > com.beefe.picker.PickerViewPackage;
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:28:
> > Error: Packagecom.reactnativenavigation does not exist import
> > com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:29:
> > Error: Packagecom.reactnativenavigation.react does not exist import
> > com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost;
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:30:
> > Error: Packagecom.reactnativenavigation.react does not exist import
> > com.reactnativenavigation.react.ReactGateway;
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:36:
> > Error: Symbol not found public class MainApplication extends
> > NavigationApplication {
> > ^   シンボル: Class NavigationApplication
> > /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:45:
> > Error: Symbol not found
> > protected ReactGateway createReactGateway() {
> > ^   シンボル:   Class ReactGateway   場所: Class MainApplication
> > /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/com/aitem/MainActivity.java:8:
> > Error: Packageandroid.support.annotation does not exist import
> > android.support.annotation.Nullable;
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/com/aitem/MainActivity.java:12:
> > Error: Packagecom.reactnativenavigation does not exist import
> > com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/com/aitem/MainActivity.java:18:
> > Error: Symbol not found public class MainActivity extends
> > NavigationActivity {
> > ^   シンボル: Class NavigationActivity /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/com/aitem/MainActivity.java:21:
> > Error: Symbol not found
> > protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> > ^   シンボル:   Class Nullable   場所: Class MainActivity
> > /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:44:
> > Error: Method does not override super
> > @Override
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:46:
> > Error: Symbol not found
> > ReactNativeHost host = new NavigationReactNativeHost(this, isDebug(), createAdditionalReactPackages()) {
> > ^   シンボル:   Class NavigationReactNativeHost   場所: Class MainApplication
> > /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:47:
> > Error: Method does not override super
> > @Override
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:52:
> > Error: Symbol not found
> > return new ReactGateway(this, isDebug(), host);
> > ^   シンボル:   Class ReactGateway   場所: Class MainApplication
> > /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:55:
> > Error: Method does not override super
> > @Override
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:68:
> > Error: Symbol not found
> > new PickerViewPackage(),
> > ^   シンボル:   Class PickerViewPackage   場所: Class MainApplication
> > /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:70:
> > Error: Class FBSDKPackageのコンストラクタ FBSDKPackageは指定された型に適用できません。
> > new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
> > ^   期待値: 引数がありません   検出値:    CallbackManager   理由: 実引数リストと仮引数リストの長さが異なります
> > /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:72:
> > Error: Symbol not found
> > new RNCWebViewPackage(),
> > ^   シンボル:   Class RNCWebViewPackage   場所: Class MainApplication
> > /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/MainApplication.java:79:
> > Error: Method does not override super
> > @Override
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/com/aitem/MainActivity.java:20:
> > Error: Method does not override super
> > @Override
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/com/aitem/MainActivity.java:22:
> > Error: Symbol not found
> > super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
> > ^   シンボル:   変数 super   場所: Class MainActivity /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/com/aitem/MainActivity.java:26:
> > Error: Symbol not found
> > PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
> > ^   シンボル:   メソッド getPackageManager()   場所: Class MainActivity
> > /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/com/aitem/MainActivity.java:48:
> > Error: Method does not override super
> > @Override
> > ^ /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/com/aitem/MainActivity.java:50:
> > Error: Symbol not found
> > super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
> > ^   シンボル:   変数 super   場所: Class MainActivity ノート:/Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/android/app/src/main/java/com/aitem/com/aitem/MainActivity.javaは推奨されないAPIを使用またはオーバーライドしています。
> > ノート:詳細は、-Xlint:deprecationオプションを指定して再コンパイルしてください。 Error25個
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
>
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation
> warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
>
> See
> https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7s 145 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 143 up-to-date
> Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for
> details. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device
> connected and have set up your Android development environment:
> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
>
> Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
>
> Error: Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
> at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:707:11)
> at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:726:15)
> at runOnAllDevices (/Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:299:19)
> at buildAndRun (/Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:135:12)
> at /Users/tenna/Downloads/aitem/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:65:12
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Answer (score 0):

1. click on android folder
2. click on app folder
3. click on src folder
4. click on java folder

click on MainApplication.java file and remove `Packagecom.reactnativecommunity.webview` in line 9

use latest updated one
`npm i react-native-webview`